# Getting 503 error after every 30 seconds with akka and node js env

Tags: scala, docker, timeout, akka, aws-elb

we have created one api to export patient details in csv file, this export request takes 2.5 min to execute.
we are using below technology for this app: Scala, akka, nginx and react/node js as front end.

when i will hit on export link, request got executed and able to see in logs.
but immediately after 30sec got error on browser console `GET /export/request 503 (service unavailable )` with java script error in promise block.

after refering akka documentation i have increased ideal-timeout setting to 240s.

application.conf

```
   http {
    server {
      request-timeout: 240s
       idle-timeout: 240s
    }
  }
```

and it works on my local/development env. /export/ request was executed in 2 min.

after deploying this change at TEST env. issue is still there getting 503 after 30 sec.
on TEST env. application is running with docker env.

request flow/application setup:

```
Internal AWS load balancer => EC2 instance => nginx proxy (listing :80) => front end app (react js app) => backend (scala and akka)
```

i have not found any configuration key which has set to 30s.

Could you please help me with this ?

Many thanks

Comment: but if i check in backed akka/scala log seems request executed successfully with 200 response.  log : 2021-07-19 15:39:53,588 [ApiServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-455] INFO  akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl -GET /engine/export/details/6a434ca3-ffdb-43e3-a92d-7486631544c0? -> 200 OK (141040 milliseconds)

Comment: Does the react app really talk directly to the backend, or does it go via the proxy? Seems odd to have load balancing on the app but not the backend.

Comment: @Tim Yes react app call backend through proxy only

Comment: In which case the timeout is happening in that proxy process, not in the backend server. So check the timeouts in the proxy

Comment: proxy setting i have increased timeout settings and they are working/affecting:  default.conf file of nginx proxy location / {
        proxy_pass http://paris-web;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_read_timeout 100;
        proxy_connect_timeout 100;
        proxy_send_timeout 100; 

    }

Comment: This question is no longer about Scala or Akka. I suggest you ask a new question with different tags and possibly in a more appropriate group.

Comment: Were you able to fix the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your problem is on any intermediary proxy. You can perform your request with curl and check the response header `Server`:

```
curl -v -s -o /dev/null your_hostname/export/request
```

If it were akka you'd see a line as follows:

```
< Server: akka-http/10.2.4
```

Hopefully you can get more insights on your issue with this technique

Comment: tried to access ,but still request terminated after 30 sec .  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:31 --:--:--     0                 Curl Command: curl --request GET --header "Content-Type: text/csv(UTF-8)" --header "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" --header "Client-Realm:${REALM_ID}" "https://${MY_HOST}/engine/patients/export/details/38fa509d-0c96-4f7a-8ab6-c023863712d6?dataset=${DATASET_ID}" > test_data.csv

Comment: using Curl command able to export all records in csv file, seems issue at UI technology or Proxy, but on local everything is fine : Curl command : curl --request GET --header "Content-Type: text/csv(UTF-8)" "http://${HOST}/engine/export/details/31a0686a-21c6-4776-a380-99f61628b074?dataset=${DATASET_ID}" > export_data.csv.

Comment: Server: nginx/1.17.10 in response header with 503 status code .. please suggest any other way to troubleshoot and fix this issue